# Converting tuple into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a tuple like this:

```
x=(('a', 'b'), ('foo', 'bar'))
```

and I want to turn it into a DataFrame like this:

```
One  Two   Three   Four
a    b     foo     bar
```

I have been trying to use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four])
```

but this error is returned:

```
runfile('D:/python codes/histo_matching.py', wdir='D:/python codes')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-1104531b1d67>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/python codes/histo_matching.py', wdir='D:/python codes')

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "D:/python codes/histo_matching.py", line 63, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 291, in __init__
    raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `list(sum(x, ()))` to flatten your `tuple` of `tuples`:

```
x = (('a', 'b'), ('foo', 'bar'))
pd.DataFrame(data=list(sum(x, ())), index=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']).transpose()

  One Two Three Four
0   a   b   foo  bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x=(('a', 'b'), ('foo', 'bar'))

foo = [[y] for a in x for y in a]
names = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

df = pd.DataFrame({names[ix]: foo[ix] for ix in range(4)})
df = df[names]

>>> print(df[names])
  One Two Three Four
0   a   b   foo  bar
```